# Gcloud CLI can't delete container image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, gcloud

When I try to delete container image from GCP registry, I get the following error:

```
$ gcloud container images delete -q --force-delete-tags gcr.io/compute-engine-XYZ/myappname@sha256:64ade15ed6dd659cd9467d34bdc4350c2310fd5d06aab4cbd5fd11751b89eb6c
Digests:   
- gcr.io/compute-engine-XYZ/myappname@sha256:64ade15ed6dd659cd9467d34bdc4350c2310fd5d06aab4cbd5fd11751b89eb6c
ERROR: gcloud crashed (V2DiagnosticException): response: {'docker-distribution-api-version': 'registry/2.0', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'date': 'Sun, 14 Aug 2022 17:13:24 GMT'
....}
Manifest sha256:64ade15ed6dd659cd9467d34bdc4350c2310fd5d06aab4cbd5fd11751b89eb6c is referenced by image sha256:5e47a7797139f91a8e5079a976f8888a9a5dcd230da888ad2fa79f83d4c95aac: None
Manifest sha256:64ade15ed6dd659cd9467d34bdc4350c2310fd5d06aab4cbd5fd11751b89eb6c is referenced by image sha256:7e1aef3093c6ef2533b9607275ad5fc4f56f1c74ee8bfe4caff0ddba7c109024: None

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

Any ideas on how to address this? How to figure out why the image is referenced by these other images, and how to maybe recursively delete them all, or something else...

Comment: `--force-delete-tags` should take care of the dependent images. The error's not very helpful. Try appending `--verbosity=debug` to see whether there's something more informative. If you just want to whack it, you could try using the Console. Does the account have sufficient permissions to delete from Cloud Storage?

Comment: The error thrown is very vague. Were you able to run the `--verbosity=debug` to see if any additional information is provided? What permission do you have assigned to cloud storage?

Comment: Debug info https://pastebin.com/raw/VuguN0AM